# Error in getting JSON from a URL

Tags: android, json

I want to get JSON from [this URL](http://android.aa8.ir/getAllDataManager.php) but it returns me this error:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("598f2de43d734f86c2ccb9e868e40332");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://android.aa8.ir/getAllDataManager.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

I use this class to get JSON in the Android:

```
public static String getData(String Address) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(Address);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            responseOutput.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
        return responseOutput.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

I think this error is because URL send me cookies or Javascript. How must i get JSON from this URL?

Comment: Did you check what your server returns when you enter `Address` into a browser's URL field?

Comment: It returns me a page that contains only JSON value

Comment: The JavaScript in your page content (first box above) changes the `location.href` of your document, replacing it by a new page: `location.href="http://android.aa8.ir/getAllDataManager.php?i=1"` Your browser does this automatically by executing the JavaScript. Your code cannot do that. You probably have to access `http://android.aa8.ir/getAllDataManager.php?i=1` directly.

Comment: That is, if the server lets you do that without the decrypted cookie `__test`.

Comment: Renardo; When i use 'http://android.aa8.ir/getAllDataManager.php?i=1' the error changes to 'http://android.aa8.ir/getAllDataManager.php?i=2'

Comment: Sorry, I cannot go into the logic of your server. The URL returns JSON code, there is no “error” that changes, only the URL sometimes seems to be redirected to …?i=2. So the technical side of the problem seems to be solved. About the logic I have no idea. – Essentially this website seems to expect a client (browser) capable of executing JavaScript and following redirects. If you want to access it from JavaCode you somehow have to compensate for that.

Comment: I used the non-free host and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

That URL is returning an HTML. Make sure that URL returns a JSON, if you are sure the URL returns a JSON, then your error is probably in `Address` (wrong address or even a typo).

The code seems to be fine. You can also check the code by requesting a JSON from a sample JSON generator, like https://www.json-generator.com/

Comment: When i ckeck URL returned content in json-generator.com it shows me proper JSON